# Assigning variables in JavaScript using new pattern

Tags: javascript

Generally we assign JavaScript variables like this:

```
var x = 10;
```

What happens when variables are assigned like this:

```
var comment = document.getElementById('comment'),
              updateInterval;
```

One is an HTML element with the id "comment", but what is `updateInterval` for?

Comment: It creates a variable `updateInterval` with a value of `undefined`.

Comment: Basically its a combination of two declarations into one statement. First `var comment = document.getElementById('comment')` and second `var updateInterval`

Comment: Suggest reading the MDN page on the `var` statement. MDN contains lots of great information and is often a good place to visit before posting questions here. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var. This popped up as the first result from a Google search for "mdn var".